# How to remove item using Paging 3 library and Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, paging, android-paging-3

I'm using Paging 3 library for first time and I wanted to know how can I remove an item.

I'm using PagingDataAdapter with a RecyclerView and loading data using Retrofit.
Maybe it's easy to reach but it's my first time using this library and I have no idea.